# includes or dasomething similar to use

Tags: javascript, json, discord.js

Any way to use .includes in json? I was wanting to check if the information given is inside json, so I tried it that way.

```js
const config = require("../../config.json");
const devsId = config.developer;

if(!devsId.includes(message.author.id)) return;

try {
  const code = args.join(" ");
  let evaled = eval(code);
  if (typeof evaled !== "string") evaled = require("util").inspect(evaled);
  message.channel.send(`\`\`\`xl\n${clean(evaled)}\`\`\``);
} catch (err) {
  message.channel.send(`\`ERROR\` \`\`\`xl\n${clean(err)}\n\`\`\``);
}
```

The content of "../../config.json" is:

```json
{
  "prefix": "!",
  "developer": {
    "VK": "418088590334230548",
    "Bobneguer": "479107440391225344"

  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

*"Any way to use .includes in json?"* `config` is an object, not JSON. Your JSON data is read and parsed in `require("../../config.json")`. There is no JSON in your code. `devsId` is an object with two properties.

You want to check if any key contains the author ID:

```
if(!Object.values(devsId).some(id => id.includes(message.author.id))) return;
```

Example:

```js
const devsId = {
    "VK": "418088590334230548",
    "Bobneguer": "479107440391225344"
};

console.log(Object.values(devsId));
console.log(Object.values(devsId).some(id => id.includes("418088590334230548")));
console.log(Object.values(devsId).some(id => id.includes("418088590334230549")));
console.log(Object.values(devsId).some(id => id.includes("479107440391225344")));
console.log(Object.values(devsId).some(id => id.includes("479107440391225345")));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly, what would json be?

Comment: @VK_ What do you mean? I don't understand the question.